# How does The LEGO Group view 3D printed parts?

Tags: lego-group, tracks, 3d-printing

I own a 3D Printer, and depending on the legality, I may or may not have 3D printed some straight tracks. Because why not?

As these parts are, hypothetically, printing, I think to myself "what would the LEGO Group think about me doing this?"

What's the LEGO Group's opinion on people 3D printing copy of their products?

Comment: I believe this depends on whether for personal use or not

Comment: If Kreo and Mega Bloks can make Lego-compatible parts, why couldn't you? They even **sell** those parts! But they probably have more lawyers than you do.

Answer (score 7):

They would obviously prefer it if you bought the parts from them.

If it's for personal use, not many people will know, and TLG probably don't want to spend much time (and money) on it, if they find out.

If you want to make money, you also have to be aware that TLG still has some patents and other rights (I don't knw for sure, but I think it's mostly around the minifig and design of sets). Kreo and Mega Bloks can do what they do, because they navigate that field and only sell stuff that is not covered by any of those rights.

If you want to exhibit any of your creations you should also think about what the organisers/groups behind the events you're thinking of exhibiting at thinks of it.